# Apply color to tabs in excel using apache poi

Tags: java, poi-hssf

Is there any way by which tabs can be given specific colors using apache poi through java?. I am using HSSF workbook.

Comment: Are you talking about applying same color to all cells of a Tab ?

Comment: define tabs : cells, sheet, other?

Comment: I want to apply different colors to sheet tabs(at the bottom where sheet name is given) in xls.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the sheet tab color using following:

```
sheet.setTabColor(int colorIndex)
```

is used for that, and so if we use

```
 sheet.setTabColor(ColorNum);
```

ColorNum = 0 : set Black Color in tab.

ColorNum = 1 : set White Color in tab.

ColorNum = 2 : set Red Color in tab.

ColorNum = 3 : set Green Color in tab.

ColorNum = 4 : set Blue Color in tab.

ColorNum = 5 : set Yellow Color in tab.

and so on.